# Using Webpack and cypress react

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, dependencies, cypress

It appears I cannot use `@cypress/react` in a project using Webpack.
Everytime I try to install it, I get the following error message:

```
while resolving: min-working-example@1.0.0
Found: webpack@5.24.4
node_modules/webpack
  dev webpack@"*" from the root project
  peer webpack@">=2" from babel-loader@8.2.2
  node_modules/babel-loader
    peerOptional babel-loader@"^=8.x" from @cypress/react@4.16.4
    node_modules/@cypress/react
      dev @cypress/react@"*" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peerOptional webpack@"^=3.x" from @cypress/react@4.16.4
node_modules/@cypress/react
  dev @cypress/react@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I am not able to fix this on my own.

In order to recreate the issue, simply

- create amn empty directory, perform `npm init`
- `npm i --save-dev Webpack cypress @cypress/react`

Comment: Have you tried npm audit

Comment: it's a nice idea, but I can't even install it in first place. I think that I would need to have some trace of this in my source code, to get started with audits

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get around this by using the legacy-peer-deps switch as outlined in the last few lines of the error message. It’s not ideal, but you should be able to make it work until the peer dependencies between the two modules line up.